# QML Creating simple PhotoViewer application

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to implement PhotoViewer application that displays photos from certain folder chosen by the user.

I checked FolderDialog documentation on Qt and I don't understand the part with viewer.Folder.

```
MenuItem {
    text: qsTr("Open...")
    onTriggered: folderDialog.open()
}

FolderDialog {
    id: folderDialog
    currentFolder: StandardPaths.standardLocations(StandardPaths.PicturesLocation)[0]
    selectedFolder: viewer.folder
}

MyViewer {
    id: viewer
    folder: folderDialog.selectedFolder
}
```

How can I propagate the selected Folder to the PhotoViewer qml?

I want this application to work like this: when it starts, the FolderDialog pops up and allows user to provide folder path,

after that three pages are shown (I will do this probably with SlideView) showing pictures from this folder in different way: lists, pathviewer and so on.
My question is that why this code doesn't show any FolderDialog when I start the application? It just freezes on the blank app.

I'm very new in QML

Main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import Qt.labs.platform
import QtQuick.Dialogs
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: rootWindow
    visible: true
    height: 700
    width: height

    MenuItem {
        text: qsTr("Open...")
        onTriggered: folderDialog.open()
    }

    FolderDialog {
        id: folderDialog
        currentFolder: StandardPaths.standardLocations(
                           StandardPaths.PicturesLocation)[0]
        selectedFolder: PhotoViewer.folder
    }

    PhotoViewer {
        height: rootWindow.height
        width: rootWindow.width
    }
}
```

PhotoViewer.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Dialogs
import Qt.labs.folderlistmodel 2.1

Item {
    id: head

    property int i: 0

    height: 500
    width: 500

    ListView {
        FolderListModel {
            id: folderModel
            folder: Folder
            nameFilters: ["*.jpg"]
        }

        Component {
            id: fileDelegate
            Text {
                text: fileName
            }
        }

        model: folderModel
        delegate: fileDelegate
    }

    // Show photos
    Image {
        id: image
        source: ""
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            console.log("fsdfsdf: " + i + " --- " + folderModel.get(i,
                                                                    "fileURL"))
            image.source = folderModel.get(i, "fileURL")
            if (++i == folderModel.count)
                i = 0
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you probably have to open the dialog, using [Dialog.open()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qt-labs-platform-dialog.html#open-method). You can use the [Component.onCompleted](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtqml-component.html#completed-signal) attached property of the Window to receive a notification when it starts.

Comment: I still can't get FolderDialog to work. When I click on a button nothing happens

Comment: I changed some code regarding Button and FolderDialog but I realized that when I make dependency of ListView height on ChooseFolderButton height when I click the button nothing appears, but when I delete that dependency, folderDialog opens. Very weird. What's more is that when I accept the folderPath no pictures are shown in a ListView